# Python standard (PEP) name to unknown class instance in function call

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I have a question about best practices in Python OOP, specifically naming conventions.

I have a `foo.py` (module?) file that is constructed as follows:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

# The question is about the below line
def do_something(master):
    try:
        master.x += 1
    except AttributeError:
        pass
```

The `main` module instantiates `foo` and then calls the `do_something` function of the `foo.py` to change the value of the `x` value of the `foo` instance.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import foo

self = foo.Foo(1)
foo.do_something(self)

print(self.x)
```

My question is regarding the `do_something` function, where the variable is now called `master`, is that what people would be expecting or should it be written differently (perhaps like the below variant)?

```
def do_something(object):
    try:
        object.x += 1
    except AttributeError:
        pass
```

I would appreciate if anyone has a link to a relevant section of a PEP where this is described (if it is). Furthermore, I am asking this question on the assumption that there is a standard, just tell me if there isn't and then i'll close this question (as then it would be a subjective question).

Comment: why not make that a class method, a la: `def do_something(self)` and then you call it simply `foo.do_something()`?

Comment: I had it as a class method initially, which caused codacy to complain about it "Method could be a function" and I was wondering how to restructure this to get rid of it, as the `do_something` doesn't have any of it's own variables (at least that's how I understood it, correct me if wrong). I will add this bit to the question actually.

Comment: Generally you want to let errors like this bubble up to the caller.  It usually means that they made a mistake, and the best way of giving them all the information about that mistake is to raise an exception.  You could even do something like `except AttributeError as e: raise ValueError("I need a Foo") from e` to give context.

Comment: Definitely don't use [`object`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#object) as the name for that parameter.

Comment: There is no recommendation on how you name parameters to functions. `self` is a norm for the first arg of class methods... so your use of `self` - `self = foo.Foo(1)` is odd and may lead to confusion if others are reading your code but not wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're manipulating property(s) of the `Foo` class instance, I would simply make it a class method:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def do_something(self):
        """
            increments self.x
        """

        try:
            self.x += 1
        except AttributeError:
        # I think this should never happen.
            pass
```

And then you call it like:

```
foo = Foo(6)
foo.do_something()
print(foo.x)
```

Comment: This is the answer to the question I asked (specifically regarding the examples), even if it's not what I hoped for. While reading the comments and thinking about this, it became clear that the interaction between my real/full main and module are faulty and need refactoring.